# Timeout Expired for DecommissionPublicationTarget

Tags: core-service, database

While running the DecommissionPublicationTarget Core Service method on a well-used Publication Target I received the following error.  The same code worked fine on a less-used Publication Target.  I am using SQL Server 2013 and Tridion 2013 SP1:

> A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure
>   "EDA_SYSTEM_DECOMMISSIONPUBLICATIONTARGET". Timeout expired.  The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding. The wait operation timed out

Any ideas?

The method I am using is:

```
  client.DecommissionPublicationTarget("tcm:0-1-65537");
```

Comment: Tried `exec sp_updatestats` on your MS SQL Server DB or the equivalent on Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you decomission a "well-used" publication target, a lot of PUBLISH_STATE records may have to be deleted (and associated indexes updated). That may take a long time; longer than the configured query/command timeout and/or transaction timeout.

Note that transaction timeout can be set per CM Session (Core Service client): `client.SetTransactionTimeout`

Also note that you can use a PowerShell cmdlet to decomission Publication Targets: `Clear-TcmPublicationTarget`

Comment: I had the same problem using the core service even after I increased the binding.SendTimeout to 10 minutes. Clear-TcmPublicationTarget fixed it for me.