# Timeout Expired for DecommissionPublicationTarget Tridion 8.5

Tags: core-service, web8.5, database

The Problem with Decommissioning Publication Targets has returned in Tridion 8.5, see original Tridion 2013 Question at
[Timeout Expired for DecommissionPublicationTarget](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/8557/29)

Any suggestions on how to extend the database stored procedure timeout for EDA_SYSTEM_DECOMMISSIONPUBLICATIONTARGET ?

Each method fails after about one minute.

Calling **DecommissionPublicationTarget**

> Exception calling "DecommissionPublicationTarget" with "1" argument(s): "A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure 
>   "EDA_SYSTEM_DECOMMISSIONPUBLICATIONTARGET".
>   Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   The wait operation timed out"
>   At line:11 char:8
>   +        $client.DecommissionPublicationTarget($target.id)
>   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FaultException`1

Calling **Clear-TcmPublicationTarget**

> Clear-TcmPublicationTarget : A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_SYSTEM_DECOMMISSIONPUBLICATIONTARGET".
>   Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   The wait operation timed out
>   At line:11 char:9
>   +         Clear-TcmPublicationTarget -PublicationTargetIds $target.id
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Clear-TcmPublicationTarget], FaultException`1
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SQLException,Tridion.ContentManager.Automation.Commands.DecommissionPublicationTargetCommand

The usual fixes do not work

```
exec sp_updatestats
```

or

```
$client.SetSessionTransactionTimeout(600)
```

or
Changing database query timeout to 500 seconds

[image]

**Update**:

After restarting the CMS (mea culpa, I restarted the wrong machine previously)
The database timeout error (was 50 seconds updated to 500 seconds) went away

Now get a SendTimeout error

> Exception calling "DecommissionPublicationTarget" with "1" argument(s): "The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00. Increase the 
>   timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of 
>   a longer timeout."
>   At line:11 char:8
>   +        $client.DecommissionPublicationTarget($target.id)
>   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TimeoutException

I will change the send timeout and try again.

Comment: Did `exec sp_updatestats` do anything?

Comment: Update stats did update some indexes. Some more publications did then clear but I still have two publications left that timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a 5+ years of publishing transactions and a large number of publications to decommission.

**To fix the problem**

See SDL Community document, which details how to change the **sendTimeout**
https://gateway.sdl.com/articles/SolutionArticles/000003814?articleName=000004535

1. Exec sp_updatestats on the Content Management database
2. Edit Machine Config to change allowExeDefinition
3. Edit Machine Config to add system.transactions
4. Edit Machine Config to add service timeouts
5. Increase database query timeout in SDL Management Console (50 seconds to 600 seconds)
6. Increase the server SendTimeout and the client SendTimeout (1 minute to 10 minutes)
7. Restart the CMS to update the changes

After each publication is decommissioned, run the exec sp_updatestats.

Remember to restore the normal timeouts when you are done.